# JNI UnsatisfiedLinkError, incompatibility 2 libraries: Card.io + OpenTok

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I'm using two libraries: [card.io](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK) and [opentok](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/android/).

OpenTok is provide with a .jar file and 2 jniLibs: armeabi/libopentok.so and x86/libopentok.so.
Card.io is imported with "compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.1.2'"

Compiled, I get this structure in my APK:

```
lib
  arm64-v8a
    libcardioDecider.so
    libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so
    libcardioRecognizer.so
    libopencv_core.so
    libopencv_imgproc.so
  armeabi
    libcardioDecider.so
    libopentok.so
  armeabi-v7a
    libcardioDecider.so
    libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so
    libcardioRecognizer.so
    libopencv_core.so
    libopencv_imgproc.so
  mips
    libcardioDecider.so
  x86
    libcardioDecider.so
    libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so
    libcardioRecognizer.so
    libopencv_core.so
    libopencv_imgproc.so
    libopentok.so
  x86_64
    libcardioDecider.so
    libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so
    libcardioRecognizer.so
    libopencv_core.so
    libopencv_imgproc.so
```

But my application crashed (when I use opentok) with:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[
[zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.app-1/base.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mypackage.app-1/lib/arm, 
                          /data/app/com.mypackage.app-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, 
                          /vendor/lib, 
                          /system/lib]
]] couldn't find "libopentok.so"
```

The app is working correctly with card.io.

If I remove card.io, my APK lib is now:

```
lib
  armeabi
    libopentok.so
  x86
    libopentok.so
```

And OpenTok is now working correctly.

My guess is: because the application found a directory "armeabi-v7a", it expect to have every .so files into. But for "libopentok.so", it's only available on "armeabi".

How can I solve my issue? Do I have to copy my .so files into each directory?

Answer (score 1):

Most of devices are `armeabi-v7a` and certainely the one you use to test.
The way Android is looking for binary is to use the most appropriate set.
It cannot use libraries from `armeabi-v7a` and `armeabi` at the same time for instance.

Therefore what happen here is:

1. the system checks it's main directory `armeabi-v7a`
2. there are some `.so` files so it won't search deeper (armeabi for instance)
3. unfortunately there are some missing libraries on the `armeabi-v7a` directory (libopentok.so)

If you ever want to be compatible with a device, you must provide every `.so` file for any supported configuration.

Edit: I'm not 100% certain, but armeabi version could be compatible with armeabi-v7a. It worth a try.

Comment: Yeah I'm agree with that, but that's weird that the system won't look into "armeabi" if a .so file is missing into the armeabi-v7a folder. I don't have the control over the libopentok.so to compile it for armeabi-v7a.

Comment: Simply because they might no be compatible with each others